# Bootstrap dropdown on EngineYard

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, engineyard

I have a dropdown menu in my layout/applications.html.erb done with twitter bootstrap

```
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" > <%= current_user.name %> </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <%= link_to 'Preferinte',edit_user_path(current_user) %>
        <a href="/logout">Iesire</a>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Everything works fine on my local machine but when I uploaded it on EngineYard the dropdown won't work .

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: extensions/event.js:185 Error in event handler for 'undefined': undefined
chrome.Event.dispatchextensions/event.js:185
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage

Comment: don't think so , I tried it on firefox and safari and I get the same problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on rails 3.0?

Did you compress the rails assets before deploy? Look for server logs to see if its failing to render the required javascript assets & css stylesheets. A good place to start will be to do

```
rake assets:precompile
```

or to just disable compressing static assets in production.rb using

```
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Also ensure serving static assets is enabled in production.rb

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: I tried rake assets:precompile but it still didn't work . I'm on rails 3.1.3 and I can't find the rails logs in EngineYard .

Comment: yes ,  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I've been using jruby on ey, but hopefully this may help.  Click ssh (under your environment) to get in, then type `cd /data/yourapp/current`.  This should look familiar!  For me, I run `tail -n 300 log/trinidad.log` to see the end of the log file

Comment: I get an permission denied error , is ssh available even for the free trail accounts ?